# Multiple ranges selection fails in a VSTO COM add-in, but works perfectly in VBA, what can be wrong here?

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

When in C# VSTO add-in, the following code fails in row 2 with a generic HRESULT exception:

```
Worksheet wsheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Range test = wsheet.Range["A1:A5, C1:C5, E1:E5"];
test.Select();
```

Identical code, but written in VBA works just fine:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5, C1:C5, E1:E5").Select
End Sub
```

What can possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Do you really need to select? Can't you give a `Range Variable` that range and do your code with it?

Comment: But I can't, it fails in line 2, so I can't even assign this to a range variable.

Comment: That's a union range; try making that explicit - `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` should have a `Union` member; use it e.g. `var rng = app.Union(wsheet.Range["A1:A5"], wsheet.Range["C1:C5"]);` then `rng = app.Union(rng, wsheet.Range["E1:E5"]);`, then you should be able to do `rng.Select();`.

Comment: Also, you very very very likely don't need to `.Select` anything at all.

Comment: Yes, select was just to see it pop up on the screen if works. I did find a way around this, but the strange thing about this line of code that it was there working fine, and at one point just started throwing an exception.